# How to load my tables into Spark dataframes faster with Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I made a code that is supposed to load many tables (listed through the method `LTables`) into differents dataframes in Scala using Spark.
Here is my code:

```
LTables.iterator.foreach{
  Table=> TableProcessor.execute(sparkSession,filterTenant,Table)

    if (Table.TableDf.count()>0) {
  GenerateCsv.execute(sparkSession, Table.TableDf,Table.OutputFilename, filterTenant)
    }
}
```

In my foreach loop, I process `TableProcessor.execute` that makes an SQL query and put the result into a dataframe and process a filtering, and then `GenerateCsv` just load filtered data into a csv.

The thing is, I have a lot of tables with large amount of data to process, so the full process is very slow (I tryed with a list of 160 tables)
I know Spark is great to process a big dataframe and not that great to deal with a lot of dataframes, but I have to get tables separatly using SQL queries.

If you have solution or advice to help me make this code run faster, it would be great.

Thank's for helping

Comment: run stuff in parallel...

Comment: Yes, but how can I process 160 SQL queries at the same time and put result into dataframes ?

Comment: schedule jobs in parallel via a scheduler, not 160 though

Comment: Would it work if i just do it that way : `LTables.par.foreach{` adding `.par ` to parallelize the operation I intend to perform ?

Comment: that could work, but I doubt you would get 160 thru at once. You will end up throttling yourself in terms of own allocated resoirces.